# da.txtに保存した「どんな映画が好きですか？」と入力すると「どんな映画が好きかというと特にない」と表示したい。

Tags: c++

**問題点1**
以下のように「どんな映画が好きなの？」と聞くと本来ならば前もって作っておいたda.xtに保存した「どんな映画が好きかというと特にない」と返事がもらえるのですが
、文字化けのせいか文字が一致しない場合の「申し訳ありません。○○とはなんですか？」になってしまいます。

```
memoyの値：0bufferの値：bufferの値：なぜ映画が好きなの？
ﾈぜ映画が好きなの？とは何ですか？
```

文字化けを避けるために getline(buffer, inputmozi);  //strに文字列を格納  を使いましたがうまくいきません。

**問題点2**
bufferとbuffer2の中身を表示しようとしたのですが、うまくいかず何も表示されません。

問題点1と問題点2に関して私の方でもできる限りのデバッグをしましたが、解決できませんでした。
なので解決するまでのデバッグ方法などあれば詳しく教えてください。

環境は Windows10、Visual Studio 2019 です。

---

#### 現状のソースコード

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
    
char String[256];
int InputHandle;
int InputHandleA;
int modoru = 0;
int mozicount = 0;
int gimonnlock = 0;
int gimon = 0;

int my_str2(const char* s1, const char* s2)//ここで入力した文字列と用意された文字列を引数として扱う。

{
    //s1, s2を比較する関数を使うためだけにs2の文字列のサイズが必要なので、変数aに用意した文字列の情報s2を文字列の長さを測るための関数strlenに引数として渡す。
    const size_t a = strlen(s2);
    //無限ループする。
    for (;;) {
        //関数memcmpの返り値が0の時は一致した時なので、==0とする。
        if (memcmp(s1, s2, a) == 0)

            return 1;//入力した文字列にい指定された文字列が入っていた場合は1を返すように設定した。
//入力した文字列が最後の文字まで到達した場合は一致する文字列がないということなので0を返すようにした。
        else if (*s1 == '\0')

            return 0;//入っていなかった
//文字列が一致した場合でも一致する文字列がない場合でも入力した文字列の一文字分の文字コードのバイト数？が繰り上がるようにした。
        else

            ++s1;

    }

}

int memory = 0;
char buffer[256];//★InputHandleに入ったのは文字のデータなので、文字のデータが受け取れる変数の型にする。
char buffer2[256];
char* p;
FILE* outputfile;         // 出力ストリーム
int inputmozi = 0;
int hyouzi = 0;
unsigned char uchr;
void getline(char s[], int lim){  
    int c, i;   //getcharの受け取り用変数c、ループ用変数i  
      
    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != '\n'; ++i)  
        s[i] = c;  
      
    s[i] = '\0';  
}  
void getline(char line[], int maxline);

int main(void)
{
    printf("memoyの値：%d", memory);
    printf("bufferの値：%s", buffer);
    printf("bufferの値：%s", buffer2);

    //新しい言葉の処理

        //  キーボード入力待ち
        inputmozi = getchar();
        getline(buffer, inputmozi);  //strに文字列を格納  
        if (my_str2(buffer, "覚えて")) {
            printf("何を覚えますか？");
           ++mozicount;
            memory = 1;
            gimon = 0;
        }
        //覚えてという言葉以外の場合はメモを読み込む込んでループに入るようにした。
        else if (memory == 0) {
            outputfile = fopen("da.txt", "r");  // ファイルを読み込み用にオープン(開く)
            if (outputfile == NULL) {          // オープンに失敗した場合
                printf("cannot open\n");         // エラーメッセージを出して
                exit(1);                         // 異常終了
            }
            //fgetsがNULLになるまで繰り返す
     //fgets(str,256,lf)!=NULL
     //と同じです。このように短縮することも可能
            //★bufferには文字入力の文字列を入れたので、ここにはメモからの文字列は入れられない。なので新しくbuffer2を作る。
            while ((fgets(buffer2, 256, outputfile)) != NULL)//メモに書いた文字列をbuffer2の中に入れる。
            {
                if (my_str2(buffer, "映画") && my_str2(buffer, "好き") && my_str2(buffer, "どんな") && my_str2(buffer, "？") ||
                    my_str2(buffer, "映画") && my_str2(buffer, "好き") && my_str2(buffer, "？")) {
                    ++mozicount;
                    gimonnlock = 1;
                    if (my_str2(buffer2, "映画") && my_str2(buffer, "どんな")) {
                        hyouzi = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
               // 文字の入力の入るバッファと、メモからの文字が入るバッファ2とで一致する文字が出てきた場合
                if (strcmp(buffer, buffer2) == 0) {
                    hyouzi = 1;
                }
                // 文字の入力の入るバッファと、メモからの文字が入るバッファ2とで一致しない文字が出てきた場合
                if (hyouzi == 0) {
                    if (strcmp(buffer, buffer2) == 1) {
                        gimon = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            fclose(outputfile);          // ファイルをクローズ(閉じる)

        }
        if (memory == 1 && my_str2(buffer, "とは") or memory == 1 && my_str2(buffer, "は") or memory == 1 && my_str2(buffer, "が")) {
            ++mozicount;
            memory = 2;
        }
    //エンターキーが押されていないときでの処理
    if (memory == 2) {   
        //例えば、intとして49はそのままの値だが、charとしては49は文字コードで言う1を表す。//このような変換をしたようなもの。
        outputfile = fopen("da.txt", "a+");  // ファイルを書き込み用にオープン(開く)
        if (outputfile == NULL) {          // オープンに失敗した場合
            printf("cannot open\n");         // エラーメッセージを出して
            exit(1);                         // 異常終了
        }
        fprintf(outputfile, "%s\n", buffer); // ファイルに書く
        fclose(outputfile);          // ファイルをクローズ(閉じる)
        //fclose(fp);//ファイルに書き込んだときにウィンドウが消えるようになっているので、memoryが1になった瞬間に書き込んでいるうんぬん以前に
        //ファイルが閉じるのでウィンドウが消えてしまう。
        memory = 0;
        // return 0;//ここで0になると終了してしまうので書き込んだ後も言葉が打ち込めるようにここを消す。

    }

    if ( hyouzi == 1) {
        printf("%s", buffer2);

    }
    if (hyouzi == 0 && gimon == 1) {
        printf("%sとは何ですか？", buffer);
    }

    // 終了
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
inputmozi = getchar();
getline(buffer, inputmozi);  //strに文字列を格納
```

が間違いですね。

`getline` 関数に渡す第2パラメータは 文字列の最大長を指定する目的で 関数を自作していると
思うので `sizeof(buffer)` を指定すべきでしょう。

また、`inputmozi = getchar();` としているため 先頭の1バイト分 （全角文字の 前半部分）
が 切り取られて `getline` が呼ばれているので 先頭の全角1文字が 文字化けした状態になっています。

> デバッグ方法

Visual Studio であれば デバッグのステップ実行で [F10] [F11] や 変数の内容を確認しながら
1行づつステップ実行するのが良いでしょう。

ある程度、予想がつくならブレークポイントを設定して その周辺を重点的にするとよいかと。

[チュートリアル: Visual Studio を使用した C++ のデバッグについて理解する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger-cpp?view=vs-2019)

が参考になると思います。

Comment: どうもありがとうございます。私もprintfで中身を見てみたのですが、例えば英語でmovieと入力した際にmがなくなっていることに気が付きました。しかしk systemさんのように解決できず   scanf("%s", buffer);を使って解決しました。

Comment: getchar()は確か一文字分を得るだけなので、そのせいで一文字消されてしまったのかもしれないですし、よくよく考えると使うにはあまり相応しい関数でなかったかもしれません。ちなみに、getlineについて調べたのですがあまり詳しいことがわかりませんでした。なぜgetlineは戦闘の全角一文字を文字化けする状態にするのですか？メリットがないように思えます。

Comment: 横からすみません。ご質問の本文から第三者が読み取れるのは、ROLISXさんがご自身で作成されたgetline()関数を文字化け回避のため使用した、ということですが、どなたか別の方が作成されたものなんでしょうか。そうだとしても、回答していただいたk systemさんに聞くのは筋が違うと思います。

Comment: `getline()`関数はROLISXさんの自作関数ではなく[Cプログラミング講座第1回「getchar関数に見る入力処理」](http://web.wakayama-u.ac.jp/~takehiko/honkarac/elde/inputstream.htm)からコピーしたパクリ関数だと思われます(リンクの記事ではK&R第2版P.36を参考にしたとありますが、K&RのほうはEOFチェックがある等細部が異なります)。どういう物なのか本人は全く理解せずにコピーしただけのため、このようなコメントをしているのだと思われます。

Comment: C言語で 日本語文字列（マルチバイト文字）を編集する処理は難易度高めの処理で、わかったようでわからない間違いを犯しやすい処理の一つです。SJIS UTF8 UNICODE の文字が どのように文字を管理しているのか学習するところから始めてみてください。

Comment: はい、そうします。どうもありがとうございました。

Comment: 度々すいません。＞＞「また、inputmozi = getchar(); としているため 先頭の1バイト分 （全角文字の 前半部分）
が 切り取られて getline が呼ばれているので 先頭の全角1文字が 文字化けした状態になっています。」に関して、getchar()により先頭の1バイト分が切り取られてnputmozi = getchar(); としているため 先頭の1バイト分 （全角文字の 前半部分）
が 切り取られてgetlineに入ることで最初が「ネ」となったのはわかるのですが、その後の「ぜ映画が好きなの？」に関しても続けざまに1バイトずつ切り取られてgetlineに入ると思うので全文が文字化けして表示されないように考えたのですが、なぜ「な」以外は綺麗に「ぜ映画が好きなの？」となったのでしょうか？